# i5 desktop new power supply turns on but wont stay on

Tags: windows-10, power

Beforehand the PC turned off and had difficulty turning on at all.

Now with the new power supply it turns on normally but does not stay on. Sometimes it will turn on then turn off and start again without prompt just to shut off again.

The PC is about a decade old with original parts save for the new power supply. Said power supply was intended to fix this issue and has not done so.

Edit1: the old psu was 500w and the new is 650w.

Comment: It could be the replacement PSU is insufficient or defective, or other hardware issue, or the OS may be corrupted. To test if it's the OS that's bad. boot and run from USB (e.g., Windos RE or Ubuntu Live). If that works, then fix Windows 10, not hardware.

Comment: Dicky (i.e. faulty) power or reset buttons on the case? I've seen them go on older cheap/crap cases...